# How to configure ElastiCache Redis for Spring Data Access

Tags: redis, spring-data-jpa, jedis, amazon-elasticache

I am trying to setup ElastiCache to use with a Java Application. I have based my setup based on this documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/BestPractices.html

The EC2 instance where the Java (8) App runs is in a VPC. 
I have tried an ElastiCache instance both in VPC and no VPC. However, I always got,

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

If I install Redis myself on an EC2 instance and connect to it, the app is able to connect to the Redis Cache!

I have setup proper authorization with Security-group from EC2 to Cache-Security but no luck. I just can't make the 'connection'. Any sample connection snippet would be really helpful.

Redis is setup this way in the APP Config:

```
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    redisConnectionFactory.setHostName(<cache-node>);
    redisConnectionFactory.setPort(6397);
    redisConnectionFactory.setUsePool(true);
    redisConnectionFactory.setTimeout(3600);
    return redisConnectionFactory;
   }
```

The various versions:

```
Jedis- 2.6.2, Spring- 4.1.6, Spring-data-> 1.5.0
```

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: have you opened the port 6397 in security group, which you have provided to your redis instance?

Answer (score 1):

```
telnet redis-ip 6397
```

Determine if redis can be connected

Answer (score 0):

```
redisConnectionFactory.setPort(6397);
```

should probably be

```
redisConnectionFactory.setPort(6379); //default redis port
```